# print discord.py syntax error but I can't understand the problem

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot but it gives me an error on a simple print command and I can't understand why.

```
#iports the discord folder and commands for our bot
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord.ext import tasks

#defining veriables
#water_reminder_members = []

#sets the command prefix
Client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

#print Nuggie is ready in the console when the bot is activeted
@Client.event
async def on_ready():
    await Client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online))
    print("Bot is ready")


@Client.command()
async def list(ctx):
    nNum = len(codes)
    codesStr = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(context.author), timeout=30
    print(codesStr)

#bot's client code
Client.run('my_token')
```

and the error I get is:

```
print(codesStr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `)` at the end of the line

```
codesStr = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(context.author), timeout=30
```

And There's one more `)` at the line

```
await Client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online))
```

You should delete one of the parentheses.

Comment: There is actually another unmatched paren in the code. You can catch these unmatched parens and more! with flake8. Do `pip install flake8` and then `flake8 discord.py` to catch syntax errors before running your code.